# select 2 random members from the database table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a query below. On executing it, it returns all the results where i can see multiple records for each single memberid.

I want to select the profiles of two members randomly chosen without any performance issue.

```
SELECT
  a.memberid,
  a.category_id,
  a.content,
  a.count_cid,
  a.importance
FROM tb_profilingdata a,
  tb_member b
WHERE a.memberid = b.memberid
    AND a.category_id IN($catstr)
    AND a.memberid NOT IN('$mid',$seen)
    AND b.gender = 'male'
ORDER BY a.memberid, a.category_id
```

[image: Result of this query]

I tried some queries for choosing one random record

```
SELECT
  r1.memberid
FROM tb_profilingdata AS r1
  JOIN (SELECT
      (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT(memberid)) FROM tb_profilingdata)) AS memberid) AS r2
WHERE r1.memberid >= r2.memberid
ORDER BY r1.memberid ASC
LIMIT 1
```

But it chooses in total 1 record out of **tb_profilingdata** whereas i want records of one randomly chosen member.

I tried the same query with **tb_member**, but it is possible that a member present in tb_member might not have its entries in **tb_profilingdata..**

Please suggest me a good way out with least performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

May be that will help you:

SELECT [something] FROM [source] WHERE [conditions] **ORDER BY RAND()** LIMIT 2

Comment: You forgot `LIMIT 2` at the end.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() has a lot of performance issues.. It is not good for very large tables..

Comment: plus it will produce total 2 records, whereas i want to produce results of 2 members.  means any number of records for each member but it should have total 2 members

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() has a lot of performance issues....

Ok. Then you can use cache for the result. You can save 2 members into the file or even select (for example once per hour) ordered by rand() for example 100 users then put them into the separated table where you can make select again for only 2 members. Then you can sometimes change 100 users in the separated table...

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT [something] FROM [source] WHERE [conditions] ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 then you will always have 2 different members

Comment: then i will not get all records of each member

Answer (score 0):

This query is untested unless you provide some sample data

```
SELECT
  a.memberid,
  a.category_id,
  a.content,
  a.count_cid,
  a.importance
FROM tb_profilingdata a
  left join (select
           memberid
         from tb_member
         group by memberid
         order by rand()) b
    on a.memberid = b.memberid
WHERE a.category_id IN($catstr)
    AND a.memberid NOT IN('$mid',$seen)
    AND b.gender = 'male'
ORDER BY a.memberid, a.category_id
```